# I wonder how can I implement a CursorLoader using for each row a different view group

Tags: android

I've recently searched and got some ideias for my problem, but still couldn't solve it.

In my Android App I have a CursorLoader bringing information from SqLite3. When I display this information, according to the type of it (this type is saved in DB), I will have a different ViewGroup.

Just to clarify a little more, I am using the concept of cards, each card has different layout and also different actions.

The number of cards is huge and I do need it to be scrollable.

I could, so far, switch the XML layout to be inflated on each row of my ListView.

What I couldn't do is having each card/row with different methods. I was wondering if extending the View base class or even the ViewGroup is a good solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you seen android.widget.Adapter#getItemViewType(int position)?

Comment: I am already using it, but still can't use independent methods for each row/view.